# What is the best way to send a simple error response message from the server to calling jQuery ajax method (e.g., responseText)?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

## what I'm trying to do...

I want to send a response message back to the calling jQuery AJAX method, that I can then use to create a warning popup message.

I tried using the HttpServletResponse method:

```
   sendError(int sc, java.lang.String msg)
```

## the problem...

***Unfortunately,*** this method wraps the ***"msg"*** string value within a larger HTML string  - which is apparently meant to be used as content for a standalone error page.

--I was hoping to just obtain the message string itself (i.e., using a jquery object method - e.g., "jqXHR").

How should I best accomplish this? (I.e., get the message back to the success/failure method without the HTML "wrapper")

***...the java server snippet...***

```
    -
    -
    -
        private List<MyDTO> performSearch(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            try
            {
                // (code to inspect searchString, etc.)
                //...forcing error for this test...
                throw new Exception("bad request yaddah...yaddah...yaddah...");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    -
    -
    -
```

***...the JQuery client snippet...***

```
    -
    -
    -
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: searchurl,                            
                    data: "searchString=" + searchString,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(jqXHR) {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR) {
                        alert("Error - bad search string used:" + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                });  
    -
    -
    -
```

---

***NOTE:***  Doing something like below, seems to work okay, but, I want to know if there is a better way to send a simple message string back to the ajax call  ...

```
    -
    -
    -       
        private List<MyDTO> performSearch(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            try
            {
                // (inspect searchString, etc.)
                //...forcing error for this test...
                throw new Exception("bad request yaddah...yaddah...yaddah...");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
                    resp.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
                    resp.flushBuffer();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }       
    -
    -
    -
```

What is the simplest/best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Return it to jQuery in the same way you would return a successful response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer after 3 years, but I'm working on a project and need to do the same thing. I use [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) as a return type for the methods in my Controller. It has a HttpStatus code (which will fire the success/error function from jQuery/AJAX) and a body (without the wrapper thing). You can rewrite your controller method like this:

**Controller**

```
private ResponseEntity performSearch(HttpSession session)
    {
        try
        {
            // (inspect searchString, etc.)
            //...forcing error for this test...
            throw new Exception("bad request yaddah...yaddah...yaddah...");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**jQuery/AJAX**

Your code is alright, just call `jqXHR.responseText()`. Also, the signature of the success function is `(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` (jqXHR comes third, not first).

**ResponseEntity**

ResponseEntity can be returned in multiple ways:

```
//Equivalent
return new ResponseEntity(someString, HttpStatus.OK);
return ResponseEntity.ok(someString);
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(someString);
```

ResponseEntity uses generics, like `ResponseEntity<T>`. So, if your method returns List you can use `private ReponseEntity<List<MyDTO>>`.

Hopefully this still helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery POST request is a success as long as you can return the value from the server side.
You don't get an error in your jquery (necessarily) even if you get it on the server.

You should distinguish between errors and successes in your server side response to the client. Jquery will execute the "success" callback either way!

Comment: Thank you, Ekreutz. I'll remain mindful of that advice going forward. ---Would you also happen to know (actually this is my primary question - sorry that it was so poorly worded) how best to get a message from the server to the "success" method, without the html wrapper that comes with using the "sendError(int sc, java.lang.String msg)" method? Thx again!   Should I be using "responseText" for this?